# I have a pandas dataframe with weeks and days in each week. How do I consider the rows where the date matches with the day?

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

```
2016-07-04  2016-06-24   154.0   320.0   923.0  1243.0  100.0   330.0  
2016-07-04  2016-06-27   195.0   384.0  1051.0  1501.0  117.0   413.0  
2016-07-04  2016-06-28   214.0   404.0  1066.0  1590.0  127.0   443.0 
2016-07-04  2016-06-29   232.0   420.0  1089.0  1677.0  139.0   466.0    
2016-07-04  2016-06-30   250.0   438.0  1099.0  1722.0  142.0   476.0  
2016-07-04  2016-07-01   264.0   443.0  1100.0  1725.0  143.0   476.0   
2016-07-04  2016-07-03   293.0   442.0  1091.0  1717.0  142.0   476.0  
2016-07-04  2016-07-04   406.0   442.0  1092.0  1718.0  142.0   476.0
```

I just want to consider the last row where the dates match. The data is for about 2 years. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df[df.iloc[:, 0] == df.iloc[:, 1]]

           0          1      2      3       4       5      6      7
7 2016-07-04 2016-07-04  406.0  442.0  1092.0  1718.0  142.0  476.0
```

Comment: @KeshavMalpani what I've written is already applying to entire dataframe.  Consider editing your question and including more data so we can better discern what the relevant conditions are.